# Distribution of $2X$

Tags: distributions, variance

I’m fairly new to statistics

I’m confused if the distribution of a random variable $X$ and $2X$ are the same, since the variance of the latter is $\mathbb{V}(2X) = 4 \mathbb{V}(X)$. Is it exactly the same distribution or the statistical distance is negligible that they are considered the same distribution?

Comment: It is certainty not the exactly the same distribution, but it may be in the same family of distributions. You are considering a particular example of a [location-scale family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family)

Answer (score 1):

No, they have a different distribution (though in some cases they still have the same distributional *family*).  There are some simple rules for deriving one distribution from the other, which depend on whether you are working with discrete or continuous distributions.  To faciliate the analysis, let $Y=2X$ denote the random variable that comes from doubling $X$.  The rules for the distributions are as follows.

---

**Discrete case:** If $X$ is a *discrete* random variable then the probability mass of $Y$ is:

$$p_Y(y) = p_X(\tfrac{y}{2}).$$

**Continuous case:** If $X$ is a *continuous* random variable then the probability density of $Y$ is:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot f_X(\tfrac{y}{2}).$$

Comment: Thanks. If X is a discrete Gaussian, is the statistical distance between X and 2X small? It is not intuitive to me yet

Comment: The Gaussian distribution is a *continuous* distribution, not discrete.  In any case, the "distance" between $X$ and $2X$ is presumably always $|X-2X| = |X|$.